# A Morsel of a Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I'm found on shoes; though not a lace,
>   I may be tied in another place.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you're a

> tongue.  After all, a shoe has a tongue, and people can get "tongue tied" when they're nervous and can't speak well.

Comment: Nice, you solved this lickety-split!

Answer (score 3):

Are you a?

> Sole/Soul (homophone)

---

*I'm found on shoes; though not a lace,*

> A shoe sole

*I may be tied in another place.*

> Two souls tied in marriage (two people)

Comment: I like this answer. However, the intended answer does not involve homophones.